# Hide element HTML when load AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner in angularJS, and do not write good English.

[image]

[image]

I have the following code

```
 <span class="custom-marker-price" ng-bind="property.rentValue"></span>
```

How can I hide the element span (IMG1) when load angular...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if im correct you should use **ng-hide** property.
Inside of span after class add ng-hide='hideIt'

and inside of controller at first line put:
$scope.hideIt=false;

And when you want to hide it just put boolean variable in true: 
$scope.hideIt = true;

You could also use ngif property.

Hope this help!

Comment: Please upvote and close thread if you found this answer helpful!

Answer (score 0):

> ## ngCloak
>
> - directive in module ng
>
> The `ngCloak` directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-cloak Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)